# MS SQL Exception: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm querying a DB using MS SQL and for some reason I get the following error: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'` even though this 'P0' isn't anywhere in my syntax...

I've read that someone has had a same issue but they were using a stored proc, something which I am not using so I don't see how his solution will work for me. (His solution being asomething about adding braces {} around the procedure call.

Anyways, below I have pasted the relevant code. Really hope someone can help me with this, getting quite frustrated.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
Connection conn = null;    

String sqlQuery = "SELECT TOP ? \n"+
                              "z.bankAccountNo, \n"+
                              "z.statementNo, \n"+
                              "z.transactionDate, \n"+
                              "z.description, \n"+
                              "z.amount, \n"+
                              "z.guid \n"+
                              "FROM \n"+
                              "( \n"+
                              "select  \n"+
                              "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY x.transactionDate, x.statementNo) AS RowNumber, \n"+
                              "x.transactionDate, \n"+
                              "x.statementNo, \n"+
                              "x.description, \n"+
                              "x.amount, \n"+
                              "x.bankAccountNo, \n"+
                              "x.guid \n"+
                              "FROM \n"+
                              "( \n"+
                              "SELECT  \n"+
                              "a.bankAccountNo,  \n"+
                              "a.statementNo,  \n"+
                              "a.transactionDate, \n"+
                              "a.description,  \n"+
                              "a.amount,  \n"+
                              "a.guid  \n"+
                              "FROM BankTransactions as a  \n"+
                              "LEFT OUTER JOIN BankTransactionCategories as b  \n"+
                              "ON a.category = b.categoryCode  \n"+
                              "WHERE b.categoryCode is null \n"+
                              ") as x \n"+
                              ") as z \n"+
                              "WHERE (z.RowNumber >= ?)";

stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
stmt.setInt(1, RowCountToDisplay);
stmt.setInt(2, StartIndex);
ResultSet rs = null;
try{
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
} catch (Exception Error){
    System.out.println("Error: "+Error);
}
```

Comment: '@P0' is your rowcounttodisplay parameter

Comment: Can you provide actual sql causing the error? It seems like you do not properly provide `RowCountToDisplay`

Answer (score 133, accepted):

SQL Server requires you to place parenthesis around the argument to `top` if you pass in a variable:

```
SELECT TOP (?)
```

Comment: Thank you! this was the problem... Been struggling with this for hours. Always a little thing isn't it... Thanks again.

Comment: This error can also appear with `INSERT` queries on syntax error binding. The number after `@P` characters can indicate which parameter produces the error (`@P3` for the third parameter, ...).

Comment: Likely time spent on this problem without SO: 3-8 hours
Time spent on this problem with SO: 55 seconds.
Thank you!

Comment: Right you are!  Thanks.

Comment: Although this is the correct, I found the solution to be @Tomasz Godziński answer

Comment: But how we place parenthesis around TOP, if we are using Pageable request

Comment: Thanks. I knew this long ago but forgot.

Comment: Glad I found this. Wonder where it might be documented and how one would know if it wasn't for SO?

Comment: how to do dynamic query, like i am creating query using StringBuilder and needs to pass that query to repository to fetch data. how can achieve this type of thing?

Answer (score 22):

In our application we have extended a depraceted `SQLServerDialect`. After change to `SQLServer2008Dialect` the problem disappeared.

Comment: I experienced the same after moving to Spring Boot 1.4 hence new Hibernate version

Comment: I got this when using `PageRequest`. I'm guessing, as per the answer from @Andomar, that it is implemented using a "top" without parentheses. As you say, updating from `SQLServerDialect` (in my case to 2012) seems to fix the issue. Apparently, this was a change in SQL Server 2005: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/59/difference-between-top-clause-in-sql-2000-and-sql-2005

Answer (score 12):

Upgraded hibernate to version 5.x and came across this issue. Had to update "hibernate.dialect" configuration from org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect to org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect. Fixed the issue!

Hibernate Doc Reference:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic

Hibernate Jira issue:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10032

Answer (score 1):

It can also be caused by a syntax error in your SQL as was the case for me

```
select * from drivel d where exists (select * from drivel where d.id = drivel.id and drivel.start_date < '2015-02-05' AND '2015-02-05' < drivel.end_date) OR exists (select * from drivel where d.id = drivel.id and drivel.start_date < '2015-02-05' AND '2015-02-05' < drivel.end_date) OR exists (select * from drivel where d.id = drivel.id and '2015-02-05' < drivel.start_date and drivel.end_date < '2015-02-05'
```

gave the message

**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P5'**

the problem was actually the balancing ')' missing at the end, namely, correct version is

```
select * from drivel d where exists (select * from drivel where d.id = drivel.id and drivel.start_date < '2015-02-05' AND '2015-02-05' < drivel.end_date) OR exists (select * from drivel where d.id = drivel.id and drivel.start_date < '2015-02-05' AND '2015-02-05' < drivel.end_date) OR exists (select * from drivel where d.id = drivel.id and '2015-02-05' < drivel.start_date and drivel.end_date < '2015-02-05')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom data source, adding property :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

in application.properties will not work.

You have to add the property as properties map in your data source bean:

```
  @Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean sqlServerEntityManagerFactory() {
    HashMap<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(sqlServerDataSource());
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    factoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return factoryBean;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Hibernate within a spring-boot app, you may set `hibernate.dialect` with following configuration property:

`spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect`

Comment: Works well with Spring Roo.  Simply provide `property add --key spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect --value org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect` at the end of a roo script.

Answer (score -2):

Call the Procedure in the below way

```
@Override
public List<Rep_Holdings> getHoldingsReport(
        int pid
)
{
    List<Rep_Holdings> holdings = null;

    Session sess = sFac.getCurrentSession();
    if (sess != null && pid > 0)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings(
            "rawtypes"
        )
        Query query = sess.createSQLQuery(
                "{CALL GetHoldingsforPF(:pid)}").addEntity(Rep_Holdings.class);
        query.setParameter("pid", pid);

        @SuppressWarnings(
            "rawtypes"
        )
        List result = query.getResultList();
        if (result != null)
        {
            if (result.size() > 0)
            {
                holdings = new ArrayList<Rep_Holdings>();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
                {
                    Rep_Holdings holding = (Rep_Holdings) result.get(i);
                    holdings.add(holding);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return holdings;
}
```

The same procedure in SQL Server

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetHoldingsforPF]
    @pid int
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
        -- Insert statements for procedure here

        declare @totalPFInv decimal(15,2);

    set @totalPFInv =  ( select  sum(totalInvestment) from Holdings where pid = @pid );

    Select hid,
           pid,
           scCode,
           numUnits,
           avgPPU,
           adjPPU,
           totalInvestment,
           cast ( (totalInvestment/@totalPFInv)*100 as decimal(10,1)) as perPF,
           totalDiv,
           cast ( (totalDiv/totalInvestment)*100 as decimal(10,1)) as divY
           from Holdings
           where pid = @pid
END
```

Comment: You seem to be answering a different question than is asked here. The OP isn't using a stored procedure, so your answer doesn't make sense.