# How to fix SqlException incorrect syntax near @p0 for Delete Top n command

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-4

I have the following statement that is failing in a C# program using LINQ to Entity Framework 4:

```
int top = 1000;
string name = "StagingTable";

using (var context = CreateObjectContext())
{
    int count = context.ExecuteStoreCommand(string.Concat("DELETE TOP {0} FROM ", name), top);
}
```

The context is created correctly (used in other parts of the program) and the table name is spelled correctly. According to Microsoft documentation, this should work to delete a maximum number of records from the table, but instead throws an exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near @p0.

I checked and rechecked the syntax of the `ExecuteStoreCommand` and could not find anything wrong.

How is it possible to use the `TOP` clause in a `DELETE` statement like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When passing a parameter to `TOP` you need to enclose it in parentheses:

```
int count = context.ExecuteStoreCommand(string.Concat("DELETE TOP ({0}) FROM ", name), top);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in a similar but unrelated post ([MS SQL Exception: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038818/ms-sql-exception-incorrect-syntax-near-p0#7038845)) when a `SELECT TOP` statement was executed from Java.

"SQL Server requires you to place parenthesis around the argument to `TOP`" if you pass it as an argument.

So code that works is:

```
int top = 1000;
string name = "StagingTable";
using (var context = CreateObjectContext())
{
    int count = context.ExecuteStoreCommand(string.Concat("DELETE TOP ({0}) FROM ", name), top);
}
```

Thanks, [Andomar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50552/andomar).